# Creating an object extending an abstract class and adding it to a sequence of the type abstract class in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, abstract-class

So I have an abstract class and a bunch of objects that extend it:

```
abstract class Command(val str: String, val help: String):
   def apply(args: Seq[String]): String

object Command:
   var all: Seq[Command] = Seq(Help, Quit, Play, Def)

   def apply(args: Seq[String]): String = 
     //Do some stuff

object Help extends Command("?", "print help"):
   def apply(args: Seq[String]): String = 
     //Do some stuff

object Quit extends Command(":q", "quit this app"):
   def apply(args: Seq[String]): String = 
     //Do some stuff

object Play extends Command("!", "play chord"):
   def apply(args: Seq[String]): String = 
     //Do some stuff

object Def extends Command("def", "define function"):
   def apply(args: Seq[String]): String = 
     case Seq(_, "!", _*) => 
      val name = args.head
      val func = args.tail  
      
      Command.all :+ Command(s"$name", func) 

      s"defined $name: $func"
    case _ => ""
```

As you can see the different objects extends the abstract class, the object Def is a text command where you first enter def to define and then the string seq in apply will be the command itself. As you can see in Def I try to add this new command to the Sequence of commands in the Command-obj. But it doesn't work, and I can't create a `val cmd = new Command(s"$name", s"Execute $name")` and then work from there. The purpose is to let the user define their own command and since the other commands are created as objects extending the abstract I don't really know how to get there. Any tips?

Comment: It feels pretty much pointless to add a new type for each command. Maybe the better approach would be to simply create `Command` as a case class and bunch of values for that case class which represent your predefined "commands".

Comment: Maybe so, but this is what I'm given and the other person wants it this way, can I still do it?

Comment: I thuogh about maybe creaing a type with an empty str argument that the user can enter, but then that command will be overwritten everytime, I want the user to for example enter ? and get a list of the commands ?, :q, !, def, and here their own defined commands.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is what you are referring to, but this does nothing because the result is thrown away.

```
Command.all :+ Command(s"$name", func)
```

You probably mean

```
Command.all = Command.all :+ Command(s"$name", func)
```

Comment: That did help but my problem was exactly what to add to the Seq, solved it now.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution:
Create a new class which will be called when they enter `name` from the `Def` class. If they wanna define a function that plays a E minor chord on a piano they write: `def Em ! p 64 67 71` so I `Def` now `name = Em` and `func = Seq("!", "p", "64", "71")` then we create a new instance of `Defined` and in `Defined` `val command = Seq("p", "64", "67", "71")`
then we add this instance (of the type `Command` (the abstract class) to the sequence of Command objects `var all: Seq[Command] = Seq(Help, Quit, Play, Def, Em)` Now when they enter the command "Em" it will call the apply-function of `Play` with `func = Seq("!", "p", "64", "71")` in Play's own apply function.  A noticeable flaw here is the Defined's apply doesn't need `args: Seq[String]` but since every other Object of the type Command needs a sequence in order to give data when calling commands I couldn't see how to avoid it.

```
class Defined extends Command(s"${Def.name}", s"Execute the function ${Def.name}"){
      //New function every new instance
      val command = Def.func.tail
        def apply(args: Seq[String]): String =
          Play(command) 
}
```

New class that is based on what they enter in the Def command:

```
object Def extends Command("def", "Define function"):
  var name = ""
  var func = Seq("")
  def apply(args: Seq[String]): String = args match
    case Seq(_, "!", _*) => 
      name = args.head //Ex. Em
      func = args.tail //Ex. ! p 64 67 71

      Command.cmdSet.add(new Defined)

      s"defined $name: ${func.mkString(" ")}"
    case _ => ""
  def getName: String = name
  def getFunc: Seq[String] = func
```

As Tim pointed out it's better if I don't change the `var all` in `Command` so I modified it to this:

```
class CommandSet:
  private var commandSet: Seq[Command] = Seq(Help, Quit, Play, Def)
  
  def add(command: Command): Unit =
    commandSet = commandSet :+ command

  def get: Seq[Command] =
    commandSet
     


object Command:
  val cmdSet = new CommandSet
  def all: Seq[Command] = cmdSet.get
```

Created a class which purpose is to hold a sequences of Commands. So now in `Def` I access `val cmdSet: commandSet` and use the `add` function and then in `object Command` instead of the sequences of commands being a var it's now `def all: Seq[String] = cmdSet.get` returning the private sequence in the class `CommandSet`

Comment: Having classes modify `var`s in other classes really isn't a good design. Rather than having  a `var` within `Command` you should have separate `CommandSet` class that contains the active list of commands. `Def` can then create a new `Command` and this can be added to the `CommandSet` to create a new `CommandSet`, avoiding all use of `var`.